# Learn the meaning of some Terms in Srivaishnava Sampradaya 2

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've been conversing with a few people in the Sri Vaishnaava Sampradaya. Often they use the below terms. I'd like to understand the meaning of it and whether they are tamil or sanskrit words.

1. "Dhaniyan" or "Thaniyan" - In Slokams
2. "Dhadiaaradhanai" and "Dhodhiyonam"

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Sir Your help here would be really valuable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Taniyan** (tamil) - a verse praising the Guru
- **TadiyArAdhanam** (sanskrit) - Literally - worship of the Vishnu's devotees; typically in the form of offering food to them. It is mentioned in the following verse from the Padmottara Purana (29.81):

> ārādhanānāṃ sarveṣāṃ viṣṇor ārādhanam param।
> tasmāt parataram proktaṃ tadīyārādhanam param।

> Of all forms of homage, the homage offered to Vishnu is the best.
> Superior to even that is the homage offered to his followers.

- **Dadhyannam** (sanskrit) - Dadhi(curd)+annam(rice); curd-rice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, "Thaniyan" means praising which Guru? The Guru who taught us the sloka or the Guru who composed the sloka? Is there any split of the "Taniyan" & "Tadiyaradhanam" word, like how you splitted up Dadhyannam? Just trying to understand better. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Taniyans are composed to enable a devotee to remember a guru. It can be any guru.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But Could you please clarify a little bit more?

Comment: The three words are unrelated. What clarification do you need?

Comment: Is there any split of the "Taniyan" & "Tadiyaradhanam" word, like how you splitted up Dadhyannam? - Any clarification on this, please? Whether the words could be split up to have some meaning?

Comment: Taniyan is a single word afaik. tadIyArAdhanam = tadIyAH + ArAdhanam. tadIyAH = viShNu bhaktas. ArAdhanam = worship.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications.